# spring boot service auth not working prop config but working with java config

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

We have a spring boot app which is backend app and serve rest api's which is using spring-boot 2.0.4. We added security through keycloak and using version - 4.0.0.Final. Initially I used java config for keycloak auth settings as shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/actuator",
            "/actuator/**",
            "/api-docs",
            "/api/**",
            "/webjars/**"
            // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array
    };

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy()         {

        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .csrf().disable().anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("SERVICE")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }
}
```

And application.properties has below settings

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8081/auth
keycloak.realm=realmName
keycloak.resource=masterdata
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.cors=true
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```

Above code works fine and its is authorizing the incoming requests which will have bearer-tokens and above code is successfully verifying whether the token has a role - SERVICE or not.

But we want to have more flexible conifg, so we are trying to get rid of java config and configure it in application.properties using below code

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=SERVICE
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*
```

And now I am getting Unauthorized code. 
I can add logs if needed. Can anybody help to show me where am I getting it wrong with appProp configs to work.